# Custom view with selective PDF output

Tags: views, files

I'm hitting a blank, I need to be able to offer a print option on some views (a pdf) and not on others.

Does anyone have an elegant way of doing this?

Thanks for looking, I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Views PDF](http://drupal.org/project/views_pdf) module.  It will allow you to add a "PDF" display to the views you choose.  From the project page:

> With this module you can output a view as a PDF document. Each field
>   of the view can be placed on the PDF page directly in the
>   administration interface. Therefore a new display called "PDF" is
>   added.

Comment: Thanks Laxman13, I was being dim and that's just what I needed.

Comment: No problem at all, glad to help